# socket.io server to relay/proxy some events

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, microservices, api-gateway

I currently have a [socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io) server spawned by a nodeJS web API server.
The UI runs separately and connects to the API via web socket. This is mostly used for notifications and connectivity status checks.

However the API also acts as a gateway for several micro services. One of these is responsible for computing the data necessary for the UI to render some charts. This operation is long-lasting and due to many reasons the computation will only start when a request is received.

In a nutshell, the UI sends a REST request to the API and the API currently uses gRPC to send the request to the micro service. **This is bad because it locks both API and UI.**

To avoid locking the socket server on the API should be be able to relay the UI request and the "computation ended" event received by the micro service, this way nothing would be locked. This could eventually lead to the gRPC server on the micro service to be removed.

Is this something achievable with socket.io?
If not is the only way for the API to spawn a secondary socket connection to the micro service for each one received by the UI?
Is this a bad idea?

I hope this is clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up not using socket.io. However this can still be done with it if the API spawns a server and has the different services connected as clients, https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ can be used.
This way messages can be "relayed" and even broadcasted from the server to both in case something happens.